# Old SF novel series possibly called "Riders"

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, symbiotes

I am looking to identify a series or at least an individual volume of pulp(ish) sf. Probably, but not definitely, dating from the 1970's.　I was given the volume in question by an aunt. I was a school boy in the mid 1980s in the north of England. The book was a small format paperback, with a whitish cover.　The blurb made it clear this was part of a series, may be the middle volume of a trilogy but I do not know for certain.

There was an extract from a previous volume that described one man looking out of a window of a spaceship.　In the distance is another ship. Another character asks a question which the first character considers, then when he looks back at the window the other ship is gone. Another detail which is probably significant is that there were aliens, probably but not definitely symbiotic aliens called "Riders". I lost the book before I was a dozen pages in so details are scant.

To sum up:

- Published before 1984
- Soft back pulp sf
- Aliens referred to as "riders"
- At least two volumes, maybe three or more. This was not volume one.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Specimen-Novel-Horror-Pete-Kahle/dp/1495230007/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?ie=UTF8&ref_=cm_cr_lh_d_bdcrb_top?

Comment: @Valorum You're a few decades too new there it would seem.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=riders&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I've found a dozen titles with alien "riders" as a plot point. It seems to be quite a common trope....

Comment: @valorum no, not The Specimen, but thank you. I had never realised that there were so many titles with rider in it!

Comment: Its been suggested to me that I might be looking for a book called The Alien Within by Adriana De Bolt. The cover looks plausible but I can't find any detailed plot description on line. Can anyone help? Should I post this up as a new question?

Comment: @dominicfonde Can't help much but The Alien Within has a sequel called Michael The Master (written by the same author but oddly under a different pseudonym, "W. Lambert III").  I've only been able to find one-sentence descriptions of either of them though, but maybe the cover of the latter is more familiar?

Comment: @starpilotsix W.Lambert III seems to have written under a lot of pseudonyms. I can't be sure this is exactly what I was searching for but it does seem enormously familiar, thank you. I will do some more digging and see what I can find, you might very well have got it.